# how to install gcc-4.7 on ubuntu 10.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

It's most simple to install packages through Synaptic Package Manager or Ubuntu Software Center but still occasionally some situation met during instaling by them cannot go through. 
Under extreme case I have to install gcc-4.7 onto ubuntu 10.04LTS. When I refreshed the repository and updated packages list, it is impossible for me to plug in gcc-4.7 unless a lot of other packages removed even those gnome packages. After googled around it seems others had done this by just type,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo  apt-get update
sudo apt-get  install gcc-4.7
sudo apt-get  install g++-4.7
```

but almost several years ago useless now.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? The fact that the repository is old doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: I tried installing gcc-4.7-base by "apt-get install gcc-4.7-base" it unistalled a lot packages even gnome cause much trouble.

Comment: I fathom gcc-4.7 conflicts with gnome on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: The repository is designed to work with that specific version -- check that the apt line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d has the correct version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about package dependencies. It may be appropriate on askubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried to install gcc-4.7-base and the prompt suggesting that a great amount of packages including gnome should be removed for installing that and I commited.
As it was finished, a system without gnome but installed with gcc-4.7.
Then I tried to install gnome again but it prompted to suggest that I should remove gcc-4.7-base again.
So in my experience, gnome and a lot of other packages are incompatible with gcc-4.7 on Ubuntu 10.04.